# How to configure and run external plugin with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, intl-tel-input

In my project I have a phone input which I want to validate using intl-tel-input plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-tel-input). I am running dev server on Webpack. Problem is, the config guidelines for this plugin clearly are not written for Webpack. 
Here is what I did, based on general advice from google and combining it with intl-tel-input guidelines:

- in webpack.config.js, initialized the plugin like so:

```
        const path = require(`path`);
        const intlTelInputPlugin = require('intl-tel-input').intlTelInputPlugin;

        module.exports = {
            mode: `development`,
            entry: `./src/main.js`,
            output: {
                filename: `bundle.js`,
                path: path.join(__dirname, `public`)
            },
            devtool: `source-map`,
            plugins: [
                new intlTelInputPlugin()
            ],
            devServer: {
                contentBase: path.join(__dirname, `public`),
                publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
                hot: true,
                compress: true
            }
        };
```

- added links to the stylesheet and images in my html and css as so:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body></body>
    </html>
```

and

```
.iti__flag {background-image: url('../../node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/img/flags.png');}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  .iti__flag {background-image: url('../../node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/img/flags@2x.png');}
}
```

- called the plugin like so:

```
// 4.4. phone validation

const phoneInput = document.querySelector('#phone');
const checkPhone = function() {
  window.intlTelInput(phoneInput);
}


submitFormButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   checkPhone();
}
```

However, running the code I get a console error saying "Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."
Changing the url of the stylesheet to a absolute path did not help, as then I get the error "Not allowed to load local resource".
Did not try to move the plugin assets to the src directory (as suggested by some), as that does not seem correct with plugins.

All in all, the plugin is not displaying.

What am I doing wrong here?
Maybe someone can point me to step-by-step guide as to how to configure and run plugin with Webpack?